# How to distinguish current macro arguments from new macro arguments when creating a macro inside another one?

Tags: macros, m4

I am trying to make this kind of construct:

```
changequote([,])dnl
define([mult_by], [define(mult_by_$1, [eval([$1] * $1)])])dnl
mult_by(7)dnl
mult_by_7(3)
```

But the result is 49 instead of 21.

---

I was hoping that `[$1] * $1` will make the trick.

Is there another approach?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the goal of the OP one has to get two concepts:

#### How to produce `$1` as the result of a macro?

There are three quoting techniques to do that:

- `[$]1`
- `$[]1`
- `$[1]`

#### How to delay `eval` macro expansion?

This snippet below produces this error `m4:fun-gen.m4:6: bad expression in eval: $1 + 5`

```
define([eval_later], eval($1 + 5))
eval_later(3)
```

There are two quoting techniques to make this work:

- Quoting all definition like that `define([eval_later], [eval($1 + 5)])`
- Quotes `eval` and arguments like that `define([eval_later], [eval]($1 + 5))`

Here we have to use the latter technique, because the former one does not work in the OP problem. Indeed, it will quote the second `$1` and make the function unable to take argument in the first place.

---

Eventually here is an answer:

```
changequote([,])dnl
define([mult_by],[define(mult_by_$1, [eval]([$]1*$1))])dnl
mult_by(7)dnl
mult_by_7(3)
```

which produces the expected `21`!